# Spring boot application does not allow get request

Tags: spring-boot

I followed tutorial from here (https://medium.com/echoenergy/how-to-use-java-high-level-rest-client-with-spring-boot-to-talk-to-aws-elasticsearch-9e12571df93e) to create a springboot- elastic search application.
I was able to do a successful POST and PUT method but GET request fails for 
me ( using PostMan).

[image]

GET fails with following exception

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-03-09T10:45:18.496+0000",
    "status": 405,
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "message": "Request method 'GET' not supported",
    "path": "/api/v1/profiles/464d06e8-ef57-49f3-ac17-bd51ba7786e2"
}
```

But I correctly added the corresponding get method in the controller

```
@RestController("/api/v1/profiles")
public class ProfileController {

    private ProfileService service;

    @Autowired
    public ProfileController(ProfileService service) {

        this.service = service;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity createProfile(
        @RequestBody ProfileDocument document) throws Exception {

        return 
            new ResponseEntity(service.createProfile(document), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ProfileDocument findById(@PathVariable String id) throws Exception {

        return service.findById(id);
    }
}
```

In the response, I can see that it allows only PUT and POST. But I could not find any config file in the server to explicitly add http methods other than the controller

[image]
Can someone please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue with your controller that I can see is, there's no `@RequestMapping("/api/v1/profiles")` at controller class level. It should be like

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/profiles")
```

You cannot specify the request path in `@RestController`'s `value` field. It means (as per javadocs);

> The value may indicate a suggestion for a logical component name, to
>   be turned into a Spring bean in case of an autodetected component.

Hope this helps.

Comment: just being curious. why did POST and PUT work but not GET?

Comment: That's a mystery to me too. I don't see how it worked for POST & PUT. There's no such thing mentioned even on Spring docs. It just says "This code uses Spring 4’s new @RestController annotation, which marks the class as a controller where every method returns a domain object instead of a view."